# Can I put java code inside the .jrxml (jasperreport)?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, scriptlet

Can I put java code inside the .jrxml?

For example, I want to put an if() or a "new ..()"

Is it possible? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put any code, you can only put expressions. So, you can put:

- `new Something(someParameter)`
- `somebool.booleanValue == true ? new Something() : new OtherThing()`;

but you can't use `if`,  `for`, `switch`, declare methods or classes.

Comment: If he'd modify the `toString` the object has, maybe he could accomplish some of the stuff he needs?

Comment: maybe.. I don't know what he needs :)

Comment: +1 Do you have an example of how to use conditionals in jrxml? I have a relad question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819812/how-can-i-use-a-conditional-textfield-in-jasperreports

Comment: @Jonas, yup, answered there ;)

Answer (score 0):

use **Scriptlet**

Jasper Design Studio 6.2 Professional ,

Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

The full tutorial [Scriptlet Example in Jaspersoft 6.x for begineers - Hello World Sample Example](https://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/scriptlet-example-jaspersoft-6x-begineers-hello-world-sample-example)