# How can I use a conditional TextField in JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, conditional-statements

I would like to have a pair of TextFields depending on a value. And the "y"-value should be adjusted depending on the empty space.

When the value is `"0"` I would like to hide the TextField.

I.e. I would like to hide the `staticText` and the `textField` if the parameter `red` is equal to `"0"` and have the blue values moved up, in the jrxml-code below:

```
  <staticText>
    <reportElement x="100" y="30" width="100" height="30"/>
    <text><![CDATA[Red items:]]></text>
  </staticText>
  <textField>
    <reportElement x="200" y="30" width="40" height="30"/>
    <textFieldExpression>
      <![CDATA[$P{red}]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
  </textField>

  <staticText>
    <reportElement x="100" y="60" width="100" height="30"/>
    <text><![CDATA[Blue items:]]></text>
  </staticText>
  <textField>
    <reportElement x="200" y="60" width="40" height="30"/>
    <textFieldExpression>
      <![CDATA[$P{blue}]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
  </textField>
```

Example of output:

```
//if blue = 3 and red = 2    if blue = 3 and red = 0    if blue = 0 and red = 2
    Red items: 2               Blue items: 3              Red items: 2
    Blue items: 3
```

These TextFields will be placed at the end of my report. How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<reportElement ...>
    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{red} == 0]]></printWhenExpression>
</reportElement>
```

You can use iReport to modify this with a pleasant UI.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I get this error: ')' expected
                value = (java.lang.Boolean)(${red == 0}); //$JR_EXPR_ID=12$

Comment: I have extended my question now. I don't know if this is possible in JasperReports.

Comment: well, simply add the `<printWhenExpression>` to other fields as well, with the appropriate condition

Answer (score 2):

In this way, no, I'm not sure it's possible.

There is an option called `Remove Link When Blank`, but it only works if you want to remove the whole line. Here you want to remove one line in specific column.

In this case I would recommend using `crosstab` or CrossTables feature.

Give the Column Group the value of X. (supposing X is the column number)
And give the Row Group the value of the color field, from here you can change the label dynamically, something like this:

```
$F{color}==null?"": ($F{color}.equals("RED")?"Red Items":"Blue Items")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
Declare RED as [class="java.lang.Number"]
```

while printing

```
$P{red}.intValue() == 0 ? null : $P{red}.intValue()
```

and enable Blank when null option of the field using

```
textField isBlankWhenNull="true">               
<reportElement x="100" y="30" width="100" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
```